# Behaviour of `std::pmr::memory_resource::allocate()` on large alignments

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

To quote N4606:

> `virtual void* do_allocate(size_t bytes, size_t alignment) = 0;`
>
> Requires: Alignment shall be a power of two.
>
> Returns: A derived class shall implement this function to return a pointer to allocated storage (3.7.4.2) with a size of at least **bytes**. The returned storage is aligned to the specified alignment, if such alignment is supported; otherwise it is aligned to **max_align**.
>
> Throws: A derived class implementation shall throw an appropriate exception if it is unable to allocate memory with the requested size and alignment.

This is IMHO unclear: What happens if the alignment is a power of two but unsupported (e.g larger than **max_align**)? Is the returned storage aligned to **max_align** or is an exception thrown?
There is of course the note concerning **a derived class implementation**, but since `std::pmr::memory_resource` is a virtual base class, every implementation must be such.

Comment: I believe the rule is for alignments less than `max_align`. If you request 2 or 4 bytes alignment, you might get 8 instead if that's the only thing the system offers.

Comment: @BoPersson But by definition, something 8-byte aligned is also 2- and 4-byte aligned.

Comment: The implementations I've seen don't throw exceptions in that case.

Comment: The answer to your question should be "yes": you'll get back memory aligned to `max_align` or an exception is thrown if the implementation can't return memory of the requested size aligned to `max_align`. The alternative would be to throw an exception on every alignment requested that isn't supported, which would render the clause on falling back to `max_align` inoperative, so that's clearly not the intent. But since "requested [...] alignment" is rather unambiguous and implies otherwise, this is probably a minor defect. It's definitely a defect if the intent was to throw on large alignments.

Comment: Thanks! I reported the issue [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/966)